# Creating a Passport.js Config Export File and Import into Index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

Although I am pretty new to software development, I have an intermediate understanding of exporting and importing data between files. However, for some reason, when trying to create a config file for Passport.js and trying to import that file into my Index.js file, I hit a brick wall. Something tells me that it could be a rookie mistake, but I'm almost sure that I probably need to move some functions over. Any advice would genuinely do. My code is below for a visual view.

Passport.JS

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const session = require('express-session');
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const db = require('./db');

app.use(session({
   key: 'session_cookie_name',
   secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
   store: new SqlDbStore({
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 3306,
   user: 'root',
   password: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   database: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   }),
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie:{
       maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
   }
}));
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

 db.connect((err) => {
     if (!err) {
         console.log("BD Connected");
     } else {
         console.log("BD Conection Failed");
         console.log(err.message);
     }
  });

 const customFields={
     firstNameField: 'usersFirstName',
     lastNameField: 'usersLastName',
     emailField: 'usersEmail',
     passwordField:'usersPassword',
     confirmPasswordField:'usersConfirmedPassword'
 };
 /*Passport JS*/
 const verifyCallback=(email,password,done)=>{
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE usersEmail= ?', [email], function(error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {
             console.log('query error: ' + error);
             return done(error);
         }

         if(results.length==0) {
              return done(null,false, {message: 'Account is not recognized.'});
         }

         const isValid=validPassword(password, results[0].EncryptHash, results[0].EncryptPassword);
         user={id:results[0].ID, email:results[0].usersEmail, hash:results[0].EncryptHash, password:results[0].EncryptPassword};
         if(isValid) {
             return done(null,user);
         } else {
             return done(null,false, {message: 'Password is incorrect.'});
         }     
     });
 };
 const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback);
 passport.use(strategy);
 passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
     console.log("Inside serialize");
     done(null, user.id);
 });
 passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done) {
     console.log('deserializeUser');
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = ? ', [userId], function(error, results) {
         done(null, results[0]);
     });
 });
 /*middleware*/
 function validPassword(password, hash, salt){    
     const hashVerify=crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 60, 'sha512').toString("hex");
     return hash === hashVerify;
 };
 function genPassword(password) {
     var salt=crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
     var genhash=crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 60, 'sha512').toString('hex');
     return {salt:salt, hash:genhash}
 };
 function checkAuthentication(req,res,next){
     if(req.isAuthenticated()){
         //req.isAuthenticated() will return true if user is logged in
         next();
     } else {
         res.redirect("/login");
     }
 };
```

Index.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const passport = require('../config/passport');
const routes = require('')('passport');


router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const saltHash = genPassword(password);
    const salt = passport.saltHash.salt;
    const hash = passport.saltHash.hash;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UsersEmail = ? ', [email], (err, results) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else if (results.length > 0) {
            res.json({ message: 'Email is already registered!' });
        } else {
            db.query('INSERT INTO Users (UsersFirstName, UsersLastName, UsersEmail, UsersPasswordHash, UsersPasswordSalt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [firstName, lastName, email, hash, salt], (err, results) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                };
                res.send(results);
            });
        }
    })
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'));

module.exports = {router, passport};
```

Update:
Question is reposted with more information on [Export and Import Passport.JS Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219826/export-and-import-passport-js-issues).

Comment: You are new to software development and can't import a module and you are managing an express server with sql and passport auth ? In commonJS you just need to write `require("path/to/module")" to import the object exported from another cjs module.

Comment: It's not the module I'm trying to import. I imported the module in the config file for passport.js... What should happen when the user submits their info is, the data should be passed over to passport to validate credentials if they are signing or encrypt credentials if they are registering.

Comment: I am basically trying to understand if I imported my passport.js config file into index to pass the data properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information is located on [Export and Import Passport.JS Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219826/export-and-import-passport-js-issues). I assumed since this post was getting no attention at all, I may have either been lacking details of my issue and explaining everything else or just had not details at all.