# Export and Import Passport.JS Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js, web-development-server

I am using node js as the backend and react as the frontend. Within the backend, I would like to create a separate file that handles every passport.js module as shown below and imports passport.js into the user.js file so that the user input data can be passed to the passport file and returned when needed. The issue that I am running into is figuring out a way to import and export the passport.js file correctly. Any help would suffice, or even a "That's not possible" would too.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const session = require('express-session');
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const db = require('./db');

app.use(session({
   key: 'session_cookie_name',
   secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
   store: new SqlDbStore({
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 3306,
   user: 'root',
   password: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   database: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   }),
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie:{
       maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
   }
}));
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

 db.connect((err) => {
     if (!err) {
         console.log("BD Connected");
     } else {
         console.log("BD Conection Failed");
         console.log(err.message);
     }
  });

 const customFields={
     firstNameField: 'usersFirstName',
     lastNameField: 'usersLastName',
     emailField: 'usersEmail',
     passwordField:'usersPassword',
     confirmPasswordField:'usersConfirmedPassword'
 };
 /*Passport JS*/
 const verifyCallback=(email,password,done)=>{
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE usersEmail= ?', [email], function(error, results, fields) {
         if (error) {
             console.log('query error: ' + error);
             return done(error);
         }

         if(results.length==0) {
              return done(null,false, {message: 'Account is not recognized.'});
         }

         const isValid=validPassword(password, results[0].EncryptHash, results[0].EncryptPassword);
         user={id:results[0].ID, email:results[0].usersEmail, hash:results[0].EncryptHash, password:results[0].EncryptPassword};
         if(isValid) {
             return done(null,user);
         } else {
             return done(null,false, {message: 'Password is incorrect.'});
         }     
     });
 };
 const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback);
 passport.use(strategy);
 passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
     console.log("Inside serialize");
     done(null, user.id);
 });
 passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done) {
     console.log('deserializeUser');
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = ? ', [userId], function(error, results) {
         done(null, results[0]);
     });
 });
 /*middleware*/
 function validPassword(password, hash, salt){    
     const hashVerify=crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 60, 'sha512').toString("hex");
     return hash === hashVerify;
 };
 function genPassword(password) {
     var salt=crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
     var genhash=crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 60, 'sha512').toString('hex');
     return {salt:salt, hash:genhash}
 };
 function checkAuthentication(req,res,next){
     if(req.isAuthenticated()){
         //req.isAuthenticated() will return true if user is logged in
         next();
     } else {
         res.redirect("/login");
     }
 };
```

User.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const passport = require('../config/passport');
const routes = require('')('passport');


router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const saltHash = genPassword(password);
    const salt = passport.saltHash.salt;
    const hash = passport.saltHash.hash;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UsersEmail = ? ', [email], (err, results) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else if (results.length > 0) {
            res.json({ message: 'Email is already registered!' });
        } else {
            db.query('INSERT INTO Users (UsersFirstName, UsersLastName, UsersEmail, UsersPasswordHash, UsersPasswordSalt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [firstName, lastName, email, hash, salt], (err, results) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                };
                res.send(results);
            });
        }
    })
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'));

module.exports = {router, passport};
```

Please note that my main reason for wanting to go this root is to prevent the following code below from being accessible in the console.

```
app.use(session({
   key: 'session_cookie_name',
   secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
   store: new SqlDbStore({
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 3306,
   user: 'root',
   password: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   database: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   }),
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie:{
       maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
   }
}));
```

**Update:**
So I was able to make the following changes to get closer. However, I get an error message that says "Missing Credentials" for passport-local.

Changes to code:
User.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const session = require('express-session');
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

//----------------------------------------- BEGINNING OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('../config/ppc.js')(passport);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/index'));
/*passport middleware*/
function genPassword(password) {
    var salt=crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    var genhash=crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 60, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    return {salt:salt, hash:genhash}
};
function checkAuthentication(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        //req.isAuthenticated() will return true if user is logged in
        next();
    } else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
};    
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const saltHash = genPassword(password);
    const salt = saltHash.salt;
    const hash = saltHash.hash;

    db.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UsersEmail = ? ', [email], (err, results) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else if (results.length > 0) {
            res.json({ message: 'Email is already registered!' });
        } else {
            db.query('INSERT INTO Users (UsersFirstName, UsersLastName, UsersEmail, UsersPasswordHash, UsersPasswordSalt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [firstName, lastName, email, hash, salt], (err, results) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                };
                res.send(results);
            });
        }
    })
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    }, function(err, user, info){
      console.log(err, user, info);
      if(err) {
          res.render ('login ', {Title:' Login ', ErrorMessage: err. Message});
      }
      if(!user) {
          res.render ('login ', {Title:' Login ', ErrorMessage: info. Message});
      }
       return req.logIn(user, function(err){
        if(err) {
          res.render ('login ', {Title:' Login ', ErrorMessage: err. Message});
        } else {
          return res.redirect('/project');
        }
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
module.exports = router;
```

ppc.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./db');


module.exports = function (passport) {
    db.connect((err) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("BD Connected");
        } else {
            console.log("BD Conection Failed");
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    });
    const customFields={
        firstNameField: 'firstName',
        lastNameField: 'lastName',
        emailField: 'email',
        passwordField:'password',
        confirmPasswordField:'passwordConfirmation'
    };
    /*Passport JS*/
    const verifyCallback=(email,password,done)=>{
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE usersEmail= ?', [email], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('query error: ' + error);
                return done(error);
            }

            if(results.length==0) {
                return done(null,false, {message: 'Account is not recognized.'});
            }

            const isValid=validPassword(password, results[0].UsersPasswordHash, results[0].UsersPasswordSalt);
            user={id:results[0].ID, email:results[0].usersEmail, hash:results[0].UsersPasswordHash, salt:results[0].UsersPasswordSalt};
            if(isValid) {
                return done(null,user);
            } else{
                return done(null,false, {message: 'Password is incorrect.'});
            }     
        });
    };
    const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback);
    passport.use(strategy);
    passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
        console.log("Inside serialize");
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done) {
        console.log('deserializeUser');
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = ? ', [userId], function(error, results) {
            done(null, results[0]);
        });
    });
    function validPassword(password, hash, salt){    
        const hashVerify=crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 60, 'sha512').toString("hex");
        return hash === hashVerify;
    };    
}
```

Code Returned:

```
BD Connected
{ email: 'jondoetech@outlook.com', password: '1234' } null false { message: 'Missing credentials' }
Error: No default engine was specified 
and no extension was provided at new View
```

Comment: The code written on your express server will never be accessible from the browser console, you do not have to worry about it. that lives only into your server. A good practice is to keep secrets, API keys, etc... in environment variables that you can access with `process.env` signature.

Comment: That was the next move actually after long thinking. Prior to me doing that, I want to ensure that the log in works. However, the message returns “Credentials missing”. Not sure why though…

Comment: Which template engine do you use? I think this error is related to the template engine

Comment: @ Adbdurrahim Ahmadov, I am using node js as the backend and react as the frontend. I’m unsure if that would mean the template engine would be html or js. I know it can’t be ejs for sure.

Comment: Maybe I should remove the view? I’m doing some research and I don’t see a lot of people have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I had to do to resolve my issues.

For login, I had to update the code to the code below.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
// console.log(req.body);
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
//   console.log('Error: ' + err);
//   console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ' User Email: ' + user.email + ' User Salt: ' + user.salt + ' User Hash: ' + user.hash);
//   console.log('Info: ' + info);
  console.log(err, user, info);
  if(err) {
    res.json({message: err.message});
  }
  if(!user) {
    res.json({message: info.message});
  }
  req.logIn(user, function(err){
    if(err) {
      res.json({message: err.message});
    } else {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
})(req, res, next)});
```

For app.use, I needed the following app.use... Note the "require" line as that is super important to connect to the separate passport file that you are trying to import.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('../config/ppc.js')(passport);
app.use(app._router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/src/App'));
```

Now, I can hit "serializeUser," but I cannot hit "deserializeUser."

Comment: Resolving this out since my export and import works. To follow up on the deserializing issue, view the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275574/passport-js-deserializeuser-is-never-reached

Comment: I ended up just moving to my own encryption method which uses bcrypt. It was the easiest and securest way to go about this process especially with out wasting to much time. If I ever find the solution in the future, I’ll post it on GitHub and will post the link here.

More information on Bcrypt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt